# GUIs in Kinect/XNA?

Tags: user-interface, xna, kinect, xbox360

I know this probably isn't the right place to post, but, well, I'm all out of ideas. :( Do any of you know frameworks/information on how to create a nice-looking GUI for the Kinect? I'm planning on using C# and was thinking about using Kinesis.IO but the conversion and compatibility seems like a headache. Would the XNA Framework do it for me? I've googled this several times and can't seem to find any good ideas. Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by GUI for the kinect? It's an input-only device, it can't display anything, meaning it can't render a GUI.

Comment: XNA allows GUI creation. However, you won't have a GUI editor like Visual C#, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm creating an application using the Kinect and would like to have some sort of a menu that allows for gestures like swiping and selecting. Would XNA be my best bet?

Comment: When you say "application", do you mean a game (as you have tagged 'xbox360' and are referring to XNA)?  Or is your goal to create something more along the lines of a kiosk application or other type of demonstration program?  Have you downloaded and looked at the Kinect for Windows SDK Toolkit examples?

Answer (score 1):

https://neoforce.codeplex.com/

Neoforce is compatible with the 360, I haven't used it on it, but it work great for my project on the PC.